# Error "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length" in single xts element

Tags: r

I know this error is well-known and I've read many questions, but I still can't figure out why I have this problem in my case.

I have a 74-column xts object with closing prices of certain stocks (data is from a csv file). Here's what the data looks like:

```
head(clPrices_xts[1:5,1:10])
           ACINO.HLDG.N ACTELION.N ADDEX.N ALPIQ.HOLDING.N AMS ARBONIA.I ARBONIA.N ARPIDA.N ASCOM.N.10 ATTISHOLZ.N
1996-08-02           NA         NA      NA              NA  NA       700        NA       NA         NA         516
1996-08-05           NA         NA      NA              NA  NA       700        NA       NA         NA         530
1996-08-06           NA         NA      NA              NA  NA       700        NA       NA         NA         530
1996-08-07           NA         NA      NA              NA  NA        NA        NA       NA         NA         532
1996-08-08           NA         NA      NA              NA  NA       680        NA       NA         NA         540

str(clPrices_xts)
 An ‘xts’ object on 1996-08-02/2017-09-13 containing:
 Data: num [1:5900, 1:74] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
 ..$ : NULL
 ..$ : chr [1:74] "ACINO.HLDG.N" "ACTELION.N" "ADDEX.N" "ALPIQ.HOLDING.N" ...
 Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
 xts Attributes:  
 NULL
```

I need to manipulate this time series (ts). For example, I would like to modify the value for ACTELION.N on the first day of the ts:

```
clPrices_xts["1996-08-02"]$ACTELION.N
           ACTELION.N
1996-08-02         NA
clPrices_xts["1996-08-02"]$ACTELION.N <- 0
Warning message:
In NextMethod(.Generic) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Anyone has an idea of why I'm getting this error? To me, it seems that there's only one single element that I want to modify...

N.B. : 
Not sure if it's useful, but I transform the data from long to wide data using `reshape2::dcast` function, and then to xts:

```
as.xts(clPrices_wide[,-1] %>%
                     apply(2, function(x) ifelse(is.nan(x), NA, x))
                   , order.by = clPrices_wide$TRADE_DATE)
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. `clPrices_xts["1996-08-02"]` returns the entire row, not just one value and `clPrices_xts["1996-08-02"] <- 0` doesn't throw an error.

Comment: You are completely correct Rui. I've edited the code to add `$ACTELION.N`.
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the message because you are selecting a row with multiple positions and length > 1 but only writing one value. For you to select only one, yo should specify indexes for row and column writing for example: `clPrices_xts["1996-08-02", "ACTELION.N"] <- 0`

I hope that is the problem. Cheers !,

EDIT:
I found another solution, by adding a comma within the brackets:

```
clPrices_xts["1996-08-02",]$ACTELION.N <- 0
```

works as well.

Comment: Thanks Carles, that was the problem.
I don't understand why though. I thought that by adding "$ACTELION" I was selecting a specific column. Is that not the case ?

Comment: $ACTELION would select the column which have the _Actelion_ name, and that will be taken/stored as a vector. If you want to then  select some specific number/Date from that vector you could specify the position. With the dataset iris in R, You could do as follows: ```data(iris)
iris$Sepal.Length[1]``` to select the first value of the Sepal.Length column. Nevertheless, I am more used to select staff as shown above. I hope this answers the question. For your interest, I would check a package that is really useful to work with select, filtering, etc which is `dplyr` :). Cheers !

Comment: Thanks Carles. I'm only beginning with dplyr (and R in general), so I don't alway think about it.

Comment: cont'd (pressed on enter too fast...)

However, I'm not sure it can help me in this case, because I need to access the values by dates, since its daily data ranging from 1996 to 2017.
Still, dplyr will definitely be useful on a later stage! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
clPrices_xts["1996-08-02",] <- c(0)
```

Comment: Also note: you are getting warning message and not error message that means the instruction will work wherever it is valid

Comment: This replaces the whole row, which is not what I want to do.
Still, thanks.

Comment: if you want to replace single column or multiple columns then try like this :                                                                                    clPrices_xts["1996-08-02",c("ACTELION.N ","ADDEX.N")] <- c(0)        
 , that is specify the columns